# FFT in Matlab : wrap around effect, value range

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I have some questions about the usage of the FFT function in Matlab.

Here is the plot of the FFT of a wav file recording a strummed A string of a guitar (only once).

I did it with an audioread of the file:

`a = audioread(a.wav))`

and then by writing

`plot(abs(fft(a)))`.

[image]

As you can see, it has a very bad shape.
First, we can see that there is some kind of symmetry. Is it the "wrap around effect"?
Should I pad my signal with zeros?

We can also see that the values are huge. It goes up to 200000 Hz.
We are of course not interested in values that high (I work on hearable sounds).

What should I do? 
Should I simply cut the frequencies above 24000 Hz? Is there something else special to do?

Thanks a lot for your help :-)

(and excuse the potentially bad English!)

Comment: Hello Pierpo, welcome to SO! That's quite the good question, well stated, documented by a plot, etc. – Can I ask you a question? Please don't take offence, it is in no way meant to imply anything negative about you. The question is: Where did you learn that you can use the FFT for frequency analyses (some university course, where, about what)? And did your teachers only talk about the FFT, or was this information embedded into some lecture about spectral estimation (was there mention of periodogram, Welch's method, stochastic processes, AR processes – anything like that)? Thank you!

Comment: Hello! Well, I barely had any classes about Signal Processing. I had a course about Signal Processing this year, but the content was too poor to bring me anything. That's why I can make huge mistakes (sorry about that). If you really want to know, I study at the Ensimag in France! The course in question was not from the Ensimag, though.

Comment: Thanks for answering! As I said, there's nothing wrong with your question. It's just that I often see questions here where people know to use an FFT, but apparently not much beyond that, and was wondering whether in some disciplines students are left with such barebones information.

Comment: By the way, if you are looking for a (imho) good book on Signal Processing, have a look at [Introduction to Signal Processing](http://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/intro2sp/) by Sophocles J. Orfanidis. The PDF is available for free on his website (see link).

Comment: @A.Donda  FYI: In many biology sub-disciplines, students with no math/engineering background often use expensive point-and-click software for signal analysis without being taught any fundamentals (IMO, this is a very serious problem in the field).  When said students come across a new published methodology which doesn't have an implementation in any available software, the only way forward is to self-study the fundamentals of signal processing and try out their schools MATLAB license.  On that end, Q&A sites like this are the best way to get started.

Answer (score 4):

The x-axis in your plot does not have the unit Hertz (Hz). The way you created the plot, it will be the index of the frequency in the frequency vector.. As your input signal appears to be about 200'000 samples long, the FFT is that long too. If you want the axis to be in Hertz, you will have to create a frequency vector that contains the corresponding frequency for every sample in the FFT.

I'll show you how to do this in an easy example, which you can adapt to your needs:

First let's create some test signal:

```
fs = 8000;               % sampling frequency: 8kHz
t = 0:1/fs:0.1;          % create a time vector
x = cos(2*pi*100*t);     % Testsignal: cosine with 100Hz
```

Now we calculate the FFT. As FFT-routines only work with vectors whos length are a power of 2, we calculate the FFT length and then do the FFT.

```
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(length(t));
X = fft(x,NFFT);
```

The frequency resolution of the FFT is `fs/NFFT`. As the length of the FFT vector is `NFFT` and the frequency starts at zero (DC), frequency vector is

```
f = (0:(NFFT-1)) * fs/NFFT;
```

So we can create a plot:

```
plot(f,abs(X));
```

[image: FFT]

You see that the peak is almost exactly at 100Hz, just as we specified. The next thing you'll notice: Our sampling frequency is `fs=8000Hz`, so according to the Nyquist theorem, the maximal frequency can be `fs/2 = 4000Hz`. The part above 4000Hz is the negative part of the frequency axis which is visible between 4000Hz and 8000Hz due to aliasing.

Now MATLAB offers the function `fftshift` to rearrange the vector `x` in order to have a plot from -fs/2 to +fs/2 instead of 0 to fs. The only thing it does is, it takes the part between 4000Hz and 8000Hz and moves it to -4000Hz to 0Hz.
You will therefore have to create the frequency vector accordingly.

```
X_shifted = fftshift(X);
f_shifted = (-NFFT/2:NFFT/2-1) * fs/NFFT;
```

[image: FFT shift]

Now the peaks are at +- 100Hz, as you would expect for a cosine.

Long story short: find out the sampling frequency and create a frequency vector. Then either plot the two-sided spectrum using `fftshift` or simply ignore the negative frequencies, as the FFT will always be symmetric for real input values.

Comment: Good answer! But could be even better if you'd mention the use of `fftshift` and would associate later frequency bins with negative frequencies...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I am very grateful :-) I'm sure it will be very helpful! I can't use Matlab right now, but I will have a look at it tomorrow. By the way, can you recommend me any paper or book about signal processing? Available online and for free, if possible... Thanks again :-)

Comment: The x-axis cannot have "samples" as a unit, because "sample number" is proportional to time, while the independent variable of the Fourier transform is frequency.  As I said in my answer, the units of the x axis are FFT coefficient index.

Comment: Exactly @BenVoigt! X axes is Frequency bin indices (equivalent to fft coefficient index). Not samples!

Comment: Of course I didn't mean time samples, but frequency samples. As the DFT is a sampled version of the DTFT i chose this name. I see that this can be quite misleading, so i changed it. Thank you for your input, Ben Voigt and Kostas

Answer (score 2):

The right hand half of the output is the negative frequency content (Essentially, it exists because your guitar string allows waves to propagate in both directions at once).

Your x axis also is not frequency right now, it is FFT coefficient index.

You should plot your FFT via

```
plot([(-numel(a)/2):(numel(a)/2-1)] * fs / numel(a), 20*log10(abs(fftshift(fft(a)))))
```

where `fs` is the sampling frequency.

For a deeper understanding you should read a good tutorial, I was able to find this one that looks good: http://www.gaussianwaves.com/2014/07/how-to-plot-fft-using-matlab-fft-of-basic-signals-sine-and-cosine-waves/

Comment: "_negative frequency content (Essentially, it exists because your guitar string allows waves to propagate in both directions at once)_". What do you mean? Is there really a relationship between the existence of negative frequencies and propagation in both directions? What directions do you mean?

Comment: Seconded. The sound that is recorded does not show its origin from a guitar string anymore. The reason there is negative frequency content is that Fourier coefficients refer to complex harmonics but the signal to be analyzed / reconstructed is real-valued.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'll have a look at it when I will be able to use Matlab again :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: It isn't a casual relationship, but both effects come from families of solutions of partial differential equations.  In particular, negative and position velocities are equally valid solutions to the wave equation, and if complex exponentials are used as the orthogonal family of basis functions, the conjugate is always equally valid as a solution to any differential equation with real coefficients.

Comment: @A.Donda: The microphone membrane also vibrates in accordance with the wave equation, permitting wave propagation in multiple directions.

Comment: The spatial dimension of either the string or the microphone membrane are completely irrelevant to the properties of the recorded signal, which is a pure time series. Therefore irrelevant are the wave equation, partial derivatives, and propagation directions. The only thing that is relevant are the properties of the Fourier transform of real-valued time series.

Comment: Just generate an artificial time series, e.g. `t = 0 :0.01:100*pi; x = sin(30*t);`, and look at its Fourier transform, and you will find the exact same effect of negative frequency components, even though this time series has never even remotely touched a string or a membrane. If you want to give it a physical interpretation, that would be the harmonic oscillator, governed by an ordinary differential equation, but again no space, no partials, no directions.

Comment: But even simpler, throw a die twenty times and look at the FT of the series of numbers that come up. Seriously, negative frequencies in the FT have nothing to do with wave propagation.

Comment: FFT is a version of DFT. There are no negative frequencies.

Comment: @Kostas: The DFT is periodic.  Negative frequency vs frequency above fs/2 vs frequency on the order of 10000 fs is just a matter of giving a name to the equivalence class.

Comment: Positive and negative frequencies do exist. E.g. imagine `cos(x) = (exp(i*x)+exp(-i*x))/2`. Using the definition of the Fourier transform will lead to dirac impulses at +- the frequency. The frequencies above fs/2 exist (as @BenVoigt explained) due to the symmetry of the DFT.

Answer (score 1):

Well...

First of all, this information should be available by your teacher.

Continuing, I will assume that you know what a digital audio signal is. Granted that, you must understand that MATLAB does not care if inside a vector are data regarding an analogue audio signal, the statistics of potato growth in India, the amount of rain in Africa or the amount of solar storms. When you create an object of audiorecorder class and pass to it a vector, MATLAB sends the corresponding signal to your speakers. By corresponding signal I mean the values that an analogue current would have.

The next point is, how this values are computed but for this you should look at DA/AD conversion.

As with the audio reproduction, fourier transform coefficients follow the same fashion. MATLAB does not care what is passed in the `fft` function. It just do the computations.

These computations are just a fast and efficient way to calculate the discrete fourier transform of a sequence/signal/what_ever. The actual method is called **Fourier Transform**. It is only in "pen and paper" since it actually demands "analogue" information. If we move at the digital domain (i.e. inside a computer) then we have a **Discrete Fourier Transform**. Which is also slow. In order to make it fast, some intelligent guys found ways of bit handling (literally) and reduced the necessary computations by far. This method is called **FAST** Fourier Transform. **Note bold** that this is ONLY an algorithm and NOT an implementation of the algorithm,

This algorithm is being implemented with various ways. One can be considered as the most fast but is also an expensive one. This way is the FFTw, I think is developed by MIT... you can check it by writing in MATLAB `help fft` and see the last entries of the help text or check at the documentation. Must be said that there other pretty fast FFT implementations, as the Ooras (if I write the name correctly) and the KissFFT.

Either way, FFT is just an DFT and by that it is meant that it keeps all of DFT properties, as the "reflection" that you can observe.

Into audio, the unit of the x axes, if you not treat them and just do the `plot(abs(fft(a)))`, is **FREQUENCY BIN INDEX**. No frequency, no samples, no anything else. Frequency bin index. Nothing more, nothing less.

So the question that you should have by now is: "What is this bin and how is connected with frequencies in an audio signal".

FFT has a trade off. Either you see the whole signal (zoom out in time) and you can also have great analysis on frequency (zoom-in in frequency), or you just analyze a frame of the signal (zoom-in in time) and lower detail of frequencies (zoom-out in frequency). The reason that this is a trade off is because if you just do an FFT on the whole signal you can observe the "average" energy that is contained in each frequency bin. If you want to see how this energy varies with the evolution of the signal, you have to have frames and thus lower your frequency analysis.

The relation of frequency bin and actual frequency of the signal can be given by the delta F of the FFT. The delta F is calculated by the formula:

```
Df = Fs/N
```

Where Df is the delta f (also called as fft analysis), Fs is the sampling frequency and N is the amount of samples that are passed to FFT. So, given the same Fs, e.g. 44100Hz, if you have a signal of 44100 samples the FFT will have an analysis of 1Hz. If you have a signal of 22050 samples, then the FFT will have an analysis of 2 Hz.

This means that each FFT coefficient will represent the energy that is in a range of frequencies specified by the Df.

So, if you want to have Hertz in you x axes you should make the vector of X values and just plot it with your signal.

Here is a sample code (it might has errors... I did not check it) :

```
[signal, fs] = audioread('a.wav'); % Load your wav file
Df = fs/max(size(signal)); % Calculate the Df
f = 0:Df:fs; % Construct the frequency vector for the X axes

signal_f = abs(fft(signal)); % Get the FFT of the signal
plot(f, signal_f(1:length(f)) % Plot the frequency vector and only the valuable information in signal_f
```